# Can't restart eclipse after crash

Tags: java, eclipse, stack-overflow

At some point my eclipse crashed and ever since that moment every time i try to restart it, it fails and I get the following exception in my logs:

```
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:109)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.SafeChunkyInputStream.find(SafeChunkyInputStream.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.SafeChunkyInputStream.find(SafeChunkyInputStream.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.SafeChunkyInputStream.find(SafeChunkyInputStream.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.SafeChunkyInputStream.find(SafeChunkyInputStream.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.SafeChunkyInputStream.find(SafeChunkyInputStream.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.SafeChunkyInputStream.find(SafeChunkyInputStream.java:98)
```

I was able to workarond the problem by removing the folder .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources but in this way I've lost all my run history and I'd like to recover that. Is there any more specific file that I can remove to solve this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out the problem was hidden somewhere in a *.snap file.

I was able to solve the problem by running the command:

```
 find . -name "*.snap" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

within the  .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources folder.

Comment: The only think that worked for me. Hard to know which .snap-file is the problem.

Comment: Thank you too. Had the same problem. Definitely worked! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Go to eclipse folder path in command prompt(shell) Run command eclipse -clean

Or

Delete old workbench(First copy all project present inside it). Start Eclipse. Once it starts try to put some folders from workbench and up the eclipse. It goes successful try with next bunch. You have to do trial and error way

Comment: I've already tried the -clean option and it didn't help. As per the new workspace I'm already using that solution but is suboptimal as I've lost a lot of stuff (i.e. my run configurations).

Comment: According to me then you have to do this by trial and error way

Comment: I have over 100 project in my workspace, and over 9000 files distributed across over 1000 directories in the org.eclipse.core.resources folder. Moving those one by one is not an option. It would take me less to recreate from scratch my run configurations. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: This kind of problems always occurs in .metadata folder. So you need to investigate this folder only

Comment: The problem actually is caused by the .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources folder. That has a 4 subfolders (.history, .projects, .root and .safetable) and each of them is plenty of subfolder. Moving them around without a clue of what am I doing is not gonna work IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the lock file `.metadata/.lock` in the workspace directory did the trick for me.